# Return a triangle-like shape of integers with rows equal to the given integer using javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

What would be the most efficient way to get a triangle-like shape of integers with rows equal to the given integer. Also, the first line should start with just one integer and after every new line, increments one character till it is also equal to integer?

E.g. If I input 5, I want this to return:

```
5
55
555
5555
55555
```

Or if I input 3, I will get:

```
3
33
333
```

---

What I have tried so far:

```js
var n = 5;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var x = (n.toString().repeat(n) + '\n').repeat(n);   
}

document.getElementById('output').textContent = x;
```

```css
#output {
padding: 10px;
background-color: #000;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 16px;
white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build the string incrementally and repeat according to the current iteration.

```js
var n = 5;
var x = '';

for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    x += n.toString().repeat(i) + '\n';
}

document.getElementById('output').textContent = x;
```

```css
#output {
padding: 10px;
background-color: #000;
color: #FFF;
text-size: 16px;
white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Just need to change your for loop to `(i = 1; i <= n; i++)` and it works beautifully. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

I would make use of two loops. The inner loop would output the number, looping until it is less than the outer loop plus 1 (to cover the first output). The outer loop would handle line breaks. Both would **add** to the existing `textContent` with `+=`.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
var n = 5;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
    document.getElementById('output').textContent += n;
  }
  document.getElementById('output').textContent += "\n";
}
```

```css
#output {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 16px;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Also note that you're looking for **[`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size)** rather than `text-size`.

Comment: This works beautifully too. Thanks man. And that text-size is a typo lol Thanks for pointing that out.